# differentiation inconsistent problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the analytical solution of the k partial derivative of equation X_21(x) in [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF2dZ.png)

and I calculated the same solution as Mathematica
which is X_2dA(x), but its curve is unexpected

on the other hand, the curve obtained using first principle X_2dF(x), is same as my expectation.

so, how come they have difference? where does it arise?
[link to the calculation graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v2i8opvi5k)

update: I find the issue myself when simplifying its derivative and heres the typed version
\begin{align}
\theta_1(x)&=x
\\
r_1(x)&=\frac{4a^2-C^2-D^2}{4a-2(Dsin(x)+Ccos(x))}
\\
O(x)&=\frac{r_1(x)+(\frac{(R+r_c)^{2}-k^2(R-r_c)^2}{4r_1(x)})}{R+r_c}
\\
X_{21}(x)&=\frac{R+r_c}{2}O(\theta_1(x))+\frac{(R-r_c)k}{2}\sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{-k}\frac{R+r_c}{R-r_c}\sqrt{1-O(\theta_1(x))^2})^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: hello, I seems solved the problem myself when I try to simplify the equation for easy typing in MathJax, turns out there is a limit in the curve of unsimplified solution, thankyou for your suggestion